# Cannot access .text in a VF9 textbox

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a very simple form with a text box to enter the year wanted, and a "GO" button.  However, the textbox will only display the textbox name ("GETYEAR").  I cannot change it in either the properties nor when I run the project.  If I reference GETYEAR.TEXT I get an error that it doesn't exist.  I thought it should work the same way as in VB. Can anyone help me with why the textbox is/seems locked ?

Thank you.

Comment: I have verified that Enabled=true and Read only=False

Comment: Check to see what the `GETYEAR.VALUE` property is. If you can't find it in the Properties window, then right click on the Properties window and uncheck 'Non-Default Properties Only'.

Comment: Also when you are referencing the textbox in code, make sure to use `THISFORM.GETYEAR.TEXT`.

Comment: Thank you.  I am using (trying to use) main.getyear.text to access the string I want to compare.  The getyear.value=[None].  When I try to modify the text property in the properties window, it is disabled with "0".  I am assuming the textbox is where I can enter and display info the same as I do in VB.  I set MaxLength =4.  I havenot changed anything else.

Comment: I set up a test command button.  It has as its only line  "main.getyear.text="1234".  If I execute the project and hit the test button, I am told that property TEXT is read only.

Comment: "main" is my form name.  I also tried thisform.getyear.text with the same results.

Comment: Right, the `Text` property will only return the `value` of the textbox. So you need to update the `Value` property of the textbox. When referring to your form you should use "THISFORM" instead of the name of your form. So the code you are looking for is `THISFORM.GetYear.Value = "1234"`.

Comment: If you can't change it, then most likely it is part of a parent class. Otherwise you would be able to change its name property. For value, change value property. If its enabled property is .T. and readonly property is .F. then it is readwrite and you can change its value by giving its complete object path. Object path might be something like thisform.GetYear  or thisform.SomeContainer.GetYear etc. Objects in a form are not simply accessed as if they were local variables as in VB. Also there might be code intercepting write such as GetYear_Assign method code.

Comment: Thank you all !!!!!    I was too VB'd.  I use the VALUE property and it does eactly what I need (you can lead a horse to water...).  Again, thank you !!:)

Answer (score 0):

In vfp textbox.text property is readonly you cannot change it. Use thisform.getyear.value property instead. I think it will work